# Меню (Объект StripMenu) на форме C# странно работает

Tags: c#, winforms

Сначала опишу что вобще есть, а потом задам вопрос, всем дочитавшим до конца огромное спасибо. Вопрос может показаться глупым, но ответа на него в всеми любимом google не нашел и сделать ничего не могу, бесит до ужаса, но писать диплом надо)) помогите люди добрые.

Есть проект C# Windows Form. Пишу в Visual Studio 2012

Есть главная форма FormMain на ней менюшка (StripMenu) на которой есть пункты "файл", "сервис", "помощь" и т.д.

Есть также вторая форма FormProperties которая открывается при нажатии
на "сервис"->"свойства" в менюшке(StripMenu) первой формы, следующим кодом

```
FormProperties formProperties = new FormProperties(); // просто создаем экземпляр
formProperties.Show(); // и не модально открываем
```

На второй форме тоже есть меню с пунктом "операции" в котором находятся вложенные пункты "открыть", "добавить" и т.д.

Собственно вопрос: Кто может объяснить столь непонятное поведение как, при нажатии на "операции" в **ПЕРВЫЙ раз** форма остается в фокусе, рисуется почему-то под вызывавшей формой FormMain, т.е. если форму FormProperties схатить мышкой за заголовок и начать водить ее по всему экрану, то при пресечении с первой формой, она прекрывается ею (первая форма рисуется сверху), хотя первая форма не в фокусе, при нажатии второй и последующие разы, просто раскрывается подменю, как и должно быть и первая форма остается на заднем фоне. Почему??!!

Comment: методом тыка вычислил что данное поведение возникает, если форма вызывается из подменю, т.е. не сразу по надатию кнопки меню (StripMenu), а при вызове из выпадающего из него подменю . Например если вызывать просто из "сервис", то все хорошо, а если из "сервис"->"свойства" то криво рисуется. Ересь какая-то

Comment: Хм. Если трюк с Owner'ом не прошёл (вы пробовали?), попробуйте вручную **закрыть** меню перед тем, как создавать новое окно.

Comment: (вручную == программным путём, не дожидаясь, пока оно само закроется с потерей фокуса)

---
у меня заканчиваются комментарии, буду верхние удалять понемногу

Comment: Можете подсказать как програмно свернуть подменю? что-то не найду для этого методы , где искать хоть в ToolStripItemCollection?

Comment: Нет, не знаю. Можно попробовать установить фокус на какой-то элемент (из тех, которые принимают фокус, конечно) — например на тот, который имеет локальный фокус в первой форме. Потеря фокуса должна вызвать закрытие выпадающего меню, по идее.